# Returning value in foreach

Tags: php, module, blocks

I'm creating a function called `getAttributeTitle()` which basically as the name suggests, gets the name of the title. I have hit a wall however and tried searching many things but couldn't really find anything - my goal is to return the value in a template file `$this->getAttributeTitle` but the foreach obviously would only return the last value in the foreach - not dynamic

here's my code:

```
public function getAttributeTitle() {
    $attributeTitle = $this->getAttributes();
    foreach ($attributeTitle as $attrTitle) {
        $title = str_replace('_', ' ', $attrTitle);
    }

    return $attributeTitle;
}
```

all I want is foreach of the attribute titles - return the title in a user friendly way but not sure how - any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're pretty close. You have a couple options: return an Array or return a string from an array.

Here's how I'd return a string of all titles separated by a space:

```
public function getAttributeTitle() {
    $titles = array();
    foreach ($this->getAttributes() as $title) {
        $titles[] = str_replace('_', ' ', $title);
    }

    return implode(' ', $titles);
}
```